# Displaying event from date when click on calendar

Tags: ios, uitableview, calendar, swift2, nsdate

In my app I am using JTAppleCalendar (https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) to display a calendar. I am also using Core Data to save an event with some information in it. This information also includes a date. The goal is to be able to click on a date and have any events that contain that date to be displayed in a tableView that is in a container in the CalendarViewController. Right now I can click on a date that has an event and the tableView will show all the past events (If that date is in the past) and will show all the future events (If that date is in the Future). Heres the code in the CalendarViewController:

```
var showPastEvents = Bool() // Allows the CalendarContainView to access these
var showFutureEvents = Bool() // Allows the CalendarContainView to access these

extension CalendarVC: JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource, JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate  {

func calendar(calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: NSDate, cell: JTAppleDayCellView?, cellState: CellState) {
    (cell as? CellView)?.cellSelectionChanged(cellState)
    //printSelectedDates()

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy MM dd"

    // Allows access to CalendarEventsCVC
    let CalendarCVC: CalendarEventsCVC = self.childViewControllers[0] as! CalendarEventsCVC

    // Clicking on any date will tell CalendarEventsCVC to not show any events unless otherwise told to
    showPastEvents = false
    showFutureEvents = false
    CalendarCVC.tableView.reloadData()

    // Search for any dates that are the same as eventPastStringDate
    let requestPast = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EventsPast")
    requestPast.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "eventPastStringDate = %@", formatter.stringFromDate(date))
    requestPast.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let resultsPast = try mocPast.executeFetchRequest(requestPast)
        if resultsPast.count > 0 {
            for result in resultsPast as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if let eventPastStringDate = result.valueForKey("eventPastStringDate") as? String {

                    // Code will run here only if the date selected is an eventPastStringDate
                    if eventPastStringDate == formatter.stringFromDate(date) {
                        if date.earlierDate(currentDate).isEqualToDate(date) {
                            showPastEvents = true
                            showFutureEvents = false
                            print("showPastEvents = true")
                            CalendarCVC.tableView.reloadData()
                        } else if date.isEqualToDate(currentDate) {
                            showPastEvents = true
                            showFutureEvents = false
                            print("showPastEvents = true")
                            CalendarCVC.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    } else if eventPastStringDate != formatter.stringFromDate(date) {
                        showPastEvents = false
                        showFutureEvents = false
                        print("Hello")
                        CalendarCVC.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
    }

    // Search for any dates that are the same as eventFutureStringDate
    let requestFuture = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "EventsFuture")
    requestFuture.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "eventFutureStringDate = %@", formatter.stringFromDate(date))
    requestFuture.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {
        let resultsFuture = try mocPast.executeFetchRequest(requestFuture)
        if resultsFuture.count > 0 {
            for result in resultsFuture as! [NSManagedObject] {
                if let eventFutureStringDate = result.valueForKey("eventFutureStringDate") as? String {

                    // Code will run here only if the date selected is an eventFutureStringDate
                    if eventFutureStringDate == formatter.stringFromDate(date) {
                        if date.laterDate(currentDate).isEqualToDate(date) {
                            showFutureEvents = true
                            showPastEvents = false
                            print("showFutureEvents = true")
                            CalendarCVC.tableView.reloadData()
                        } else if date.isEqualToDate(currentDate) {
                            showPastEvents = true
                            showFutureEvents = false
                            print("showPastEvents = true")
                            CalendarCVC.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    } else if eventFutureStringDate != formatter.stringFromDate(date) {
                        showPastEvents = false
                        showFutureEvents = false
                        print("Hello")
                        CalendarCVC.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
    }
}
}
```

(eventPastStringDate is a datePicker.date that was converted to a string using the same formatter as above when the event is actually saved in a different screen)

Then in the CalendarContainerView it will only show certain events based on whether or not showPastEvents = true or showFutureEvents = true. Heres the code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let result: UITableViewCell

    if eventsPast.count > 0 && showPastEvents == true {

        let ePast = eventsPast[indexPath.row]
        let cellPast = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        // Sets labels in cell to whatever user typed in on the events page
        cellPast.titlePrototypeCell!.text = ePast.eventPastTitle!
        // Other Information Also
        result = cellPast

    } else if eventsFuture.count > 0 && showFutureEvents == true {

        let eFuture = eventsFuture[indexPath.row]
        let cellFuture = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        // Sets labels in cell to whatever user typed in on the events page
        cellFuture.titlePrototypeCell!.text = eFuture.eventFutureTitle!
        // Other Information Also
        result = cellFuture

    } else {

        let noEventCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("noEventCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        result = noEventCell

    }
    return result
}
```

I am thinking that if I can get the indexPath of the event that the eventPastStringDate/eventPastFutureDate is in then I can only display that index in the CalendarContainerView but I am not sure how to get this. Also I would have to change the numberOfRowsInSection to display the right number of cells. Any ideas? I know this is a lot of code but I felt that it would be beneficial.

Comment: Man.. way to long.. way to confusing. So a user taps a dateCell, what do you want your tableView to display?

Comment: The event that is stored in core data that is on that date

Comment: I realized this was too long and I was going to delete it but I just asked a much simpler question that is almost the same thing I'd youd like to look at my profile

Comment: So just to confirm. Is your question something to do with the calendar? or is it something to do with core data? Because, I am guessing that you will already have the core data information about that date in some array or variable right?  So is the question about something to do with the calendar? or core data?

Comment: More about core data and how to check if there is  event stored has a date attribute that is the same as the date selected and then get the index that event to be displayed

Comment: ok then. My bad. I know nothing about core data. I only know about the calendar. best of luck :<